# Obj-C objects not being released in a C callback function

Tags: objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I am using the `AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks` function in my app to provide MP3 data in chunks. I call the function as follows:

```
AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks((__bridge void *)(self), TTMAudioFile_ReadProc, NULL, TTMAudioFile_GetSizeProc, NULL, 0, &aqData.mAudioFile);
```

In this case, `self` is the containing Objective-C class.

My `TTMAudioFile_ReadProc` callback function is as follows:

```
OSStatus TTMAudioFile_ReadProc(void *inClientData, SInt64 inPosition, UInt32 requestCount, void *buffer, UInt32 *actualCount) {

    TTMAudioQueuePlayer *this = (__bridge TTMAudioQueuePlayer *)inClientData;
    NSData *data = [this.decryptor dataAtOffset:inPosition length:requestCount error:NULL];
    memcpy(buffer, data.bytes, data.length);

    NSUInteger length = data.length;
    *actualCount = (UInt32)length;

    return noErr;
}
```

This works, but the NSData isn't being released. Profiling Allocations in Instruments reveal many allocations that look like the following:

[image]

Apparently there are two extra `retain` calls in my callback function, but I don't see where I can be retaining them. Furthermore, I am using ARC, so I don't know why this is happening either.

Comment: This is really difficult to debug without seeing more code. What does `dataAtOffset` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed an autorelease pool.

The C callback function `TTMAudioFile_ReadProc` is called on a separate thread from the main thread. In this case, an autorelease pool is not automatically created, unlike when working with dispatch queues.

```
OSStatus TTMAudioFile_ReadProc(void *inClientData, SInt64 inPosition, UInt32 requestCount, void *buffer, UInt32 *actualCount) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        TTMAudioQueuePlayer *this = (__bridge TTMAudioQueuePlayer *)inClientData;
        NSData *data = [this.decryptor dataAtOffset:inPosition length:requestCount error:NULL];

        memcpy(buffer, data.bytes, data.length);
        NSUInteger length = data.length;
        *actualCount = (UInt32)length;

        return noErr;
    }
}
```